# j_spring_security_check not invoked in tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, myfaces

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.4 with myfaces 2.2.10 and primefaces 5.3. My local server works fine (tried to run it both standalone and eclipse) when I open the login screen and press the login button the following is visible in the logs:

```
...web.controller.LoginController] - <Validating login>
...AntPathRequestMatcher] - <Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/external/**'>
```

After this a transaction started and the user is validated against the database as expected.

---

**However** when I copied the whole Tomcat distribution to a remote server and deployed the same application, j_spring_security_check is not executed anymore:

```
[org.springframework.faces.support.RequestLoggingPhaseListener] - 
<Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW(1)>

[org.springframework.faces.support.RequestLoggingPhaseListener] - 
<Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE(6)>

[...web.controller.LoginController] - <No error messages during validation>
```

And after this the login screen is reloaded.

Can anyone help me why there is a difference in the behavior of the same servers and same applications? Any idea is appreciated!

I'm pretty sure that it does not have anything to do with myfaces or primefaces versions and I tried different versions but the behavior is the same...

Comment: So it works with mojarra?

Comment: as I explained in the answer for my own question, my problem was realted to tomcat config, not JSF. After setting the maxPostSize to -1, everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

for those who have the same issue I post my solution.

Of course there can be millions of reasons to cause this behavior but in my case it was the tomcat configuration... in Connector config in server.xml I've set

```
    maxPostSize="0"
```

by mistake which I tought means no limit, however I should have set

```
    maxPostSize="-1"
```

This resulted in the server cutting the post payload from the request... and causing me a lot of headache :)